# _.map() not working when playing with real data

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, underscore.js

I'm querying two collections to get the data from bills and transactions.

After I get both, I loop transactions array for each `billId`.

Once the `billId` from the transaction array matches with the `_id` from the bill array, I store the transaction under the bill array.

So instead of having:

```
bill_array = [{
    "_id": "549bf0597886c3763e000001",
    "billName": "Leasing",
    "startDate": "2014-12-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2017-10-14T22:00:00.000Z",
    "amount": 16500,
    "type": 4,
    "timestamp": "2014-12-25T11:09:13.957Z",
    "__v": 0
}]
```

I can have:

```
bill_array = [{"_id": "549bf0597886c3763e000001",
    "billName": "Leasing",
    "startDate": "2014-12-25T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2017-10-14T22:00:00.000Z",
    "amount": 16500,
    "type": 4,
    "transactions": {[all transactions]}
    "timestamp": "2014-12-25T11:09:13.957Z",
    "__v": 0}]
```

The code below is working in [my JSfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/dennislaymi/usanwkcL/), however, when I try with real data (from the db), I can't get the map to insert the new object into the bills array.
Here is the working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/dennislaymi/usanwkcL/

And here is the (not working) code on my machine:

```
app.get('/getbills', function(req, res) {
    //get all bills
    allBills = Bills.find().exec();
    //get all transactions
    allTransactions = Transactions.find().exec();
    //aggregate bills and transactions in a promise
    promise.all([allBills, allTransactions]).then(function(results) {
        var bills = results[0];
        var transactions = results[1];

        _.map(bills, function(bValue) {
            bValue.transactions = [];
            _.each(transactions, function(tValue) {
                if (tValue.billId == bValue._id) {
                    bValue.transactions.push(tValue);
                }
            });
            console.log("transactons: " + bValue.transactions);
            return bValue.transactions;
        });
        console.log(bills);
        res.send(bills);
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't you mean `bill_array = [{"_id" : "01", "value": "100"}]`?

Comment: @thefourtheye, guess it was a typo.

Comment: You could refactor your internal  `_.each` to a `_.map` (or better yet - use native `array#map`  Also note that like thefoureye said your object notation is incorrect.

Comment: You can achieve this straight forward using the populate feature of mongoose. The `population` API takes care of reference resolution.- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html.

Comment: Objects are key-value pair based structures, `bill_array = {["_id": "01", "value": "100"]}` is not valid because it doesn't have any keys.

Comment: Sorry my example was bad. I have corrected it now.

Comment: I have not yet managed to get it working. Any help will be sweet!

Answer (score 2):

`_.map` is an immutable operation, meaning that it doesn't change initial object.

If you want to overwrite it with mapped data, you should write something like:

```
bills = _.map(bills, function (bValue) {
  bValue.transactions = [];
  _.each(transactions, function (tValue) {
    if (tValue.billId == bValue._id) {
      bValue.transactions.push(tValue);
    }
  });
  return bValue;
});
```

I would also suggest using something like [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) instead of `_.each` in your case:

```
bills = _.map(bills, function (bValue) {
  bValue.transactions = _.filter(transactions, function (tValue) {
    return (tValue.billId == bValue._id);
  });
  return bValue;
});
```

Comment: is there any chance you could give me a example applied to my code? There are no enough examples on web related to _.map or _.each. At least for adding multiple arrays into a object as in my example. Thanks

Comment: Even when I'm getting the results from _.map() into a variable it still doesn't give me the outcome I wanted. Please, if you have the time, let me know what am I missing: http://jsfiddle.net/dennislaymi/usanwkcL/3/  Thanks

Comment: @DeisyLaymi see my update. I also updated your jsfiddle: [version 1](http://jsfiddle.net/usanwkcL/5/), [version 2](http://jsfiddle.net/usanwkcL/6/).